# Windows store: The image must define at least one variant without a TargetSize qualifier

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp

Submitting a Windows 10 app to the store, the store returns an error:
 *Image reference "Assets\Square44x44Logo.png": The image must define at least one variant without a TargetSize qualifier. It must define a Scale qualifier or leave Scale and TargetSize unspecified, which defaults to Scale-100.*

However, I have an Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png in the project. Also, the Windows App Cert Kit passes all tests. In fact, I could submit the app in the past.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is the ".scale-100" image the only one or do  you have an image called "Square44x44Logo.png" included in the project, too? Pretty sure that's required.

Comment: I have for Square44x44Logo:

Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png
Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png
Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of testings and trials, the solution has been to delete Bin, Obj and AppPackages folders. After that, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

`Square44x44Logo.png` is required as it's the one without a TargetSize qualifier and will be delivered by default to all devices. Windows 10 apps use app bundling, where a base bundle and specific other bundles are delivered to the devices. Specific bundles are e.g. language or display specific. So only 200dpi devices will get your `*.scale-200.*` files etc. But still, there's a default image without a qualifier necessary if there are multiple assets and this will be delivered via the base bundle.